# Magento 2 - Call list phtml by passing collection variable

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-collection, list.phtml

I have collection loaded in variable `$collection` and I want to pass collection variable in my `list.phtml`

```
$block = $viewBlock->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList')
                ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
```

So that `list.phtml` create product list according to my collection. My query is how can I pass collection variable to `list.phtml`

**Note:** I don't want to change any thing in list phtml it also include calling any custom function from block object. My product collection must be loaded by default function which is already in list phtml i.e: `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to create block `Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList.php` by overriding this function `_getProductCollection()` by extending your class from this `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{   
        /* Do whatever you want to do with your collection */  

        $this->_productCollection = $yourcollection;
        return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Now you can call your `ptml` file. Your collection has been passed to that `phtml`

```
$block = $viewBlock->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList')
                ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
```

**I hope this will help others**

Answer (score 3):

try this way....

```
   $block = $viewBlock->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\ProductList')
                    ->setCustomvalue('111111')
                    ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
                    ->toHtml();
```

and you can get value

```
$block->getCustomvalue();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to pass any custom value to list.phtml. I want to pass product collection so that magento default list.phtml will show product list with that collection.

Comment: you can pass in variable collection also try that

Comment: tried to pass it using `->setCollection($collection)` but it wasn't working. What I am trying to say I don't need change any thing in list phtml it include the calling as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$block` variable contains the content of `list.phtml` so here you just have called it.

That `list.phtml` contains `$_productCollection` that it gets it from the module `block`, in your `$block` you can do anything in that collection because the collection has already been loaded, it's too late to update it at this level.

What you can to do is to rewrite that block `Magento_Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php` and after that, you can update the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I used below code to send Product data to phtml file using plugin. and it is working fine.

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Catalog\Product;
use Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data;

class ListProduct
{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $layout;   
    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        Data $dataHelper
    ) {        
        $this->layout = $layout;         
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }

    public function afterGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        if($this->dataHelper->isEnabled()){
            $result .= $this->layout->createBlock('Namespace\Modulename\Block\Label')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::product/test.phtml')->toHtml();
        }
        return $result;        
    }
}
```

**Note :** In above code `->setProduct($product)` i used to set product data.i think you can use `->setCollection()` to achieve your thing. you can try with this way it might be help.